# NSPredicate: Combine CONTAINS with IN

Tags: core-data, nspredicate

I have a set of users in CoreData and an search field in my application. User has the properties firstname and name.

Currently I have a predicate like "user.name CONTAINS[c] %@ OR user.firstname CONTAINS[c] %@ "

This works until the user types a full name like "john smith". Even if he types "john sm" the John Smith-Object should be found.

What is the predicate to combine an array (IN) of search terms with CONTAINS?

Comment: could you help take a look at a similar question? thanks! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62380694/ios-swift-how-to-perform-sql-sum-function-using-msquery-and-nspredicate

Answer (score 16, accepted):

2.5 years later I can answer my question with a bit more complex example in swift:

```
var predicateList = [NSPredicate]()

let words = filterText.componentsSeparatedByString(" ")

for word in words{

     if count(word)==0{
           continue
     }

     let firstNamePredicate = NSPredicate(format: "firstName contains[c] %@", word)
     let lastNamePredicate = NSPredicate(format: "lastName contains[c] %@", word)
     let departmentPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "department contains[c] %@", word)
     let jobTitlePredicate = NSPredicate(format: "jobTitle contains[c] %@", word)

     let orCompoundPredicate = NSCompoundPredicate(type: NSCompoundPredicateType.OrPredicateType, subpredicates: [firstNamePredicate, lastNamePredicate,departmentPredicate,jobTitlePredicate])

     predicateList.append(orCompoundPredicate)
}

request.predicate = NSCompoundPredicate(type: NSCompoundPredicateType.AndPredicateType, subpredicates: predicateList)
```

Comment: This is probably the same as @Martin R's answer, just difference in language. You should accepted him imo.

Comment: could you help take a look at a similar question? thanks! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62380694/ios-swift-how-to-perform-sql-sum-function-using-msquery-and-nspredicate

Answer (score 39):

I don't think that you can combine "IN" with "CONTAINS" in a predicate. But you could split the search string into words, and create a "compound predicate":

```
NSString *searchString = @"John  Sm ";
NSArray *words = [searchString componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
NSMutableArray *predicateList = [NSMutableArray array];
for (NSString *word in words) {
    if ([word length] > 0) {
        NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"user.name CONTAINS[c] %@ OR user.firstname CONTAINS[c] %@", word, word];
        [predicateList addObject:pred];
    }
}
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:predicateList];
NSLog(@"%@", predicate);
```

This example produces the predicate

```
(user.name CONTAINS[c] "John" OR user.firstname CONTAINS[c] "John") AND
(user.name CONTAINS[c] "Sm" OR user.firstname CONTAINS[c] "Sm")
```

which would match "John Smith", but not "John Miller".

Comment: 5 years into iOS, and this is the first time I saw this. This should still be the accepted answer imo.

Comment: @Martin R, could you help take a look at a similar question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62380694/ios-swift-how-to-perform-sql-sum-function-using-msquery-and-nspredicate

Answer (score 5):

**Swift 4 Update:**

```
let firstName = NSPredicate(format: "firstName CONTAINS[c] %@", searchText)
let lastName = NSPredicate(format: "lastName CONTAINS[c] %@", searchText)

let orCompoundPredicate = NSCompoundPredicate(orPredicateWithSubpredicates: 
[firstNamePredicate,lastNamePredicate]
```

Use the **orCompoundPredicate** while fetching data.

Comment: could you help take a look at a similar question? thanks! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62380694/ios-swift-how-to-perform-sql-sum-function-using-msquery-and-nspredicate

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem and solved it like this:

In my NSManagedObject class (user) I added the following method, merging the two values into a single string:

```
- (NSString *)name
{
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", self.firstname, self.lastname];
}
```

Then you'll only need the following lines to match against your list, which is in my case an NSArray with user objects:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name contains[c] %@", searchString];
NSArray *filteredUsers = [users filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

Comment: this doesn't solve the problem when user searches for "lastname firstname"