# search multiple words with normalized names uisearchbar ios

Tags: ios, uisearchbar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [NSPredicate: Combine CONTAINS with IN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13479542/nspredicate-combine-contains-with-in)

I have a core data set of about 21,000 items. In an attempt to speed up search results, I normalized all the names. For example "Lion King Simba" became lion, king, simba.

It is certainly much faster, and works great if I search for lion, king, or simba, but (and I didn't realized this until the app was already released) if I search for "lion king" it does NOT find the item.

Is there a way to get a search bar with two words, such as "lion king", to compare it self with lion and king and return the result?

I did try a few google searches, but I'm not sure how to even word that question properly.

Any help would be appreciated!

Zack

Comment: You can split the search text into words and build a "compound predicate" to search for objects that contain all the words. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13479542/nspredicate-combine-contains-with-in/13481452#13481452 for the answer to a similar question.

Comment: You are welcome. I will then vote to close this as duplicate.