# How to escape a trailing backslash in an NSPredicate format string

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nspredicate

I'm using Core Data and I have a predicate like this in a fetch request:

```m
NSString *predicateStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"name like[c] '%@'",name];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:predicateStr];
```

This works great with one exception: 
sometimes it's possible that the name may end with a backslash ( "\" ) since that part is user-generated and can also come from outside the app.

When it does, I get an error like this:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
>   'Unable to parse the format string "(name like[c] 'mqcu\')"'

So I tried using `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString` like this:

```m
NSString *predicateStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"(name like[c] '%@')", [name stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\" withString:@"\\\\"]];
```

but then I get an error like this:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
>   'The backslash is a wildcard char, and cannot appear unescaped at the end of a string.'

How do I properly escape the backslash?

Comment: Please try always to copy your actual code. The first line does not compile, and enclosing `%@` in quotes in the predicate string cannot have worked at all.

Comment: Thanks corrected, the actual code is waaay more than that. I should have been more careful to not leave the quotes out tho.

Comment: I hope you did not use `stringWithFormat` to build the predicate ... ?

Comment: loool i did because parts of the predicate can change depending on a few items! let me try switching one to static....

Comment: If you post as an answer I'll accept... I'll also edit my question to include what I initially was doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should never use `stringWithFormat` to build predicates. `stringWithFormat` handles the `%K` and `%@` and the quoting differently from `predicateWithFormat`, so combining these methods can easily fail (as in your case).

If the predicate has variable parts that are
only known at runtime, you can use `NSCompoundPredicate` to create a complex predicate
dynamically (see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/13481452/1187415 for an example).

Comment: ty for NSCompoundPredicate

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what your needs are, you may be able to build your predicate using ==, BEGINSWITH, CONTAINS, etc. instead of LIKE. Then you will not need to worry about escaping special characters.

If you use LIKE or MATCHES then you must escape special characters.