# Writing an NSPredicate for 'CONTAINED_BY' text query

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, core-data, nspredicate

I am trying to construct a query of a Core Data store which retrieves an entity's attribute values when they occur in longer string;

i.e, instead of seeking instances where attribute value *contains* a (shorter) string :

```
request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"carBrand contains[c] 'merced'"]
```

I want to find instances (of the entity) whose  attribute values are found **'contained in'** an arbitrary *(longer)* string :

```
NSString* textString = @"Elaine used to drive Audis, but now owns a Mercedes";
request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%@ contains[c] carBrand", textString ];
```

(ie. retrieve array holding objects with carBrand = @"Audi" and carBrand = @"Mercedes")

In my attempts, NSPredicate doesn't seem to like expressions with the attribute name on the  right hand side and throws an error...

> [__NSCFConstantString countByEnumeratingWithState:objects:count:]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x

...is there a way of constructing such a query with the attribute name on the  left hand side - a *'contained_by'* query, as it were?

**PS**. Searching SO, I've only found [solutions by splitting the text into component words](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13481452/1079194) which, in my scenario, would be less than ideal! Is this the only type of approach that's viable?

Answer (score 1):

Build a regex string with your array and use `MATCHES` in your predicate.

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%@ MATCHES '*(Audi|Mercedes)*'", testString];
```

To filter cars based on their brand:

```
NSArray *brands = [@"Audi", @"Mercedes"];
[NSPrediate predicateWithFormat:@"carBrand IN %@", brands];
```

Comment: In my example, I wish to find *which* of the many Cars in my db have a .carBrand which match some part of the string.  Doesn't your query just confirm whether Audi|Mercedes is in the string?

Comment: Yes, this example just returns the original strings which contain either Audi or Mercedes without mutating them.

Comment: Question edited to clarify that desired outcome is the *array of entities* whose given *attribute value* matches some substring of the arbitrary dynamic search source string.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand correctly. You want the fetch result to return a string that is different then the one stored?

If that is the case, you should fetch all the strings first and then create your desired strings from that. You can make a NSString extension and call `[array valueForKey:@"methodName"]`.

A fetch predicate only filters which entries are returned, it does not mutate them.

Comment: No, Kris, my Core Data Store is of (in this example) *Car instances* **not** the text to be searched. I want my predicate to return  those instances where instance.carBrand attribute value occurs in a given piece of text.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64406/discussion-between-cate-and-kris-jurgowski).

Answer (score 0):

Decided to try implementing a `componentsSeparatedByString` approach to build a `NSCompoundPredicate`

```
//find alphabetic words omitting standard plurals
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"(?:[^a-z]*)([a-z]+?)(?:s)?\\W+" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive  error:nil];

//separate with pipe| and split into array
NSString *split = [regex stringByReplacingMatchesInString:textString options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, speciesString.length) withTemplate:@"$1|"];
NSArray *words = [split componentsSeparatedByString:@"|"];

//build predicate List

NSMutableArray *predicateList = [NSMutableArray array];
for (NSString *word in words) {
    if ([word length] > 2) {
        NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"brandName beginswith[c] %@", word];
        [predicateList addObject:pred];
    }
}
//CarBrand* object;
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
request.entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"CarBrand" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
request.predicate = [NSCompoundPredicate orPredicateWithSubpredicates:predicateList];

NSError *error =nil;
NSArray *results = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
```

This retrieves the instances found in the text; 
eg1:

> @"Elaine used to drive Audis, but now owns a Mercedes";

gives array of objects whose .brandname = "Audi",  "Mercedes", respectively .

> eg2: @"Among the cars stolen were a Ford Mondeo, a Fiat 500C and an
>   Alfa-Romeo Spyder"

yields .brandname = "Ford",  "Fiat",and "Alfa Romeo"(NB no '-') respectively.

I'm not yet accepting my own answer as it seems too much of a workaround and won't easily extend to (for example) extracting brand-name AND, say, model.

Hopefully, someone will have a better solution!