# executeFetchRequest Crashing after setting NSPredicate to NSFetchRequest

Tags: ios, sql, regex, core-data, nspredicate

I'm really stuck on this one, and I'm blaming my rusty SQL / REGEX on this one, but I hope you can help.

I have this CoreData Entity:

```m
@interface Movie : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) id genreArray;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * imdbID;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * isPlaying;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * isPromo;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * isTickets;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate * lastUpdate;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * movieID;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * movieName;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * movieName_EN;
@property (nonatomic, retain) id movieOtherNames;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * posterPicture;
@property (nonatomic, retain) etcetcetc;
```

@end

So, I want to search a Movie by NAME. The problem is that the Name can be either under movieName or movieName_EN or within ONE of the names inside the array movieOtherNames.

Currently, my futile request goes like this:

```m
    Movie* movie = nil;

    NSEntityDescription *allMovs = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Movie"
                                                inManagedObjectContext:[self mainManagedObjectContext]];
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    [request setEntity:allMovs];

    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]
                                        initWithKey:@"premiereDate" ascending:NO];
    [request setSortDescriptors:@[sortDescriptor]];

    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"$movieName contains[cd] %@ OR %@ contains[cd] $movieName OR $movieName_EN contains[cd] %@ OR  %@ contains[cd] $movieName_EN OR ANY $movieOtherNames MATCHES %@", movieName, movieName, movieName, movieName, movieName];
    [request setPredicate:predicate];
    NSError *error;
    NSArray* moviesArray = [[self mainManagedObjectContext] executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
    if(error)
        SRTLog(@"CoreData: NO movieTimes! Deal with error...");
    if([moviesArray count] > 0)
        movie = [moviesArray objectAtIndex:0];
    return movie;
```

My app is crashing when executing this code. My guess is NSPredicate. Something is VERY wrong there.

Can ANYONE help me out on how to search for a string that can contain (or be contained) in 2 fields AND an array of strings?

I'll be refreshing Stack OverFlow for any good souls out there willing to help.

Comment: Shouldn't you be using LIKE instead of CONTAINS ?

Comment: FYI, the problem with your predicate is the '%@ contains[cd] $movieName' (and similar).  You will find several questions on SO trying to address this; none with much success.  Here's one with some work arounds: [Writing an NSPredicate for CONTAINED_BY](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26778320/3985749)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you got this predicates a bit wrong. Try implementing this if it solves the issue. If not, pleas add some description of the error and the exact line.

I hope the code itself is self explanatory:

```
    NSString *movieName = @""; // get the true name value
    NSArray *predicateCompounds = @[
                                    [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"movieName LIKE[cd] %@", movieName],
                                    [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%@ LIKE[cd] movieName", movieName],
                                    [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"movieName_EN LIKE[cd] %@", movieName],
                                    [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%@ LIKE[cd] movieName_EN", movieName]
                                    ];
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSCompoundPredicate orPredicateWithSubpredicates:predicateCompounds];
```

Comment: Hi @Matic Oblak:  Thanks for Relating to My Question. I Tried your Code but It is Still Crashing when I Try to Execute the Request. Also, You didn't Include how I Could Search Within the "movieOtherNames" Array. Thanks.

Comment: The Error Occurs in THIS LINE:        
NSArray* moviesArray = [[self mainManagedObjectContext] executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

Comment: And do you get any info of the error? Maybe you simply misspelled something. What does the log say?

Comment: Hi @Matic Oblak, Thanks Again. Well... I Can't See the Error, on the Threads it Writes: [NSManagedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:error:] ()
I Have NO Clue about this Bro :s

Comment: You will most likely need a bit of effort to debug this. Double check if all the names are correct, try fetching the objects without the predicate and then start adding the predicate compounds to see what part is the cause of the crash.

Comment: Well, I've done as You Said and used the LIKE Clause instead of the Contains and I Think its Working Now, So I'll Consider this as Answered MATIC... Thanks a LOT :-)