# How to search text with a multi text query using NSPredicate?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, nspredicate

I'm trying to perform a query by multiple values.
Unfortunately I can't use the ANY operator because I've to perform a CONTAINS operation.

Exemple:

```
Obj *foo1 = [Obj objectWithName:@"John" age:42];
Obj *foo2 = [Obj objectWithName:@"Elizabeth" age:21];
Obj *foo3 = [Obj objectWithName:@"Albert" age:17];
Obj *foo4 = [Obj objectWithName:@"Marty" age:54];

NSArray *query = @[@"Joh", @"lizabe", @"arty"];
```

// This query should return `foo1`, `foo2` and `foo4`.

I tried something like but it doesn't work :

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(name CONTAINS[cd]) IN %@, query];
```

Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSMutableArray *filterArray = [NSMutableArray array];
NSArray *query = @[@"Joh", @"lizabe", @"arty"];
for (NSString *string in query)
{
     [filterArray addObjectsFromArray:[mainArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name CONTAINS[cd] IN %@", string]]];
}
```

Here **mainarray** is your objects containing array.

or try this..

```
    NSMutableArray *filterArray = [NSMutableArray array];
    NSMutableArray *predicateArray = [NSMutableArray array];
    NSArray *query = @[@"Joh", @"lizabe", @"arty"];
    for (NSString *string in query)
         [predicateArray addObject:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name CONTAINS[c] %@", string]];

   NSPredicate *compoundpred = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:predicateArray];
[filterArray addObjectsFromArray:[mainArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:compoundpred];
```

I hope this will help for you...

Comment: Yes it works, I just ended with a similar solution founded on possible duplicate. I hope there is a more elegant solution for that kind of work. Thanks you anyway.

Comment: Thanks for your proposition, as I told you, I ended with the same solution using the solution in the probably duplicate question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13479542/nspredicate-combine-contains-with-in .