# Compound Predicate

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nspredicate

I'm trying to do a compound search on core data via a `UITableView` (search and display controller):

```
let firstNamePredicate = NSPredicate(format: "fname CONTAINS[c] %@", searchText)

let lastNamePredicate = NSPredicate(format: "lname CONTAINS[c] %@", searchText)

let firstAndLastNamePredicate = NSPredicate(format: "fname contains[c] %@ OR lname contains[c] %@", searchText, searchText)

let companyPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "company CONTAINS[c] %@", searchText)

let predicate = NSCompoundPredicate(type: NSCompoundPredicateType.OrPredicateType, subpredicates: [firstNamePredicate, lastNamePredicate, companyPredicate, firstAndLastNamePredicate])

fetchRequest.predicate = predicate
```

All of the predicates work except the first and last name predicate. I can type a first name in and will get results perfectly, but as soon as I space and type the last name I'll get no results. Any idea what's wrong with my first and last name predicate?

Comment: Your firstAndLastNamePredicate definition contains some unbalanced parentheses. Is that your real code?

Comment: That's because you are using the same `searchText` for all search items. Consider what happens when you search  `fname CONTAINS[c] ''John Doe" to see why this approach is broken.

Comment: Compare http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13479542/nspredicate-combine-contains-with-in.