# Swift NSPredicate, first name AND last name NSCompoundPredicate?

Tags: swift, search, nspredicate

In my code below I am using NSPredicates specifically I am using NSCompoundPredicate to check for multiple different parameters in my search function. How would I go about searching with both the First Name AND Last Name, I am currently using AND but it does not return anything in my UITableView. All my other predicates listed in the compound predicate work great.

```
func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {

textInSearchField = searchBar.text!

if searchBar.text == ""{

  print("Searching for all clients.")
  retrieveClients()
  view.endEditing(true)
  clientTableView.reloadData()

}else{

  print("Enter a client name to search.")
  isFilteringSearch = true

  let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
  let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

  let firstAndLast = NSPredicate(format: "firstName = %@ AND lastName = %@", textInSearchField)
  let firstNamePredicate = NSPredicate(format: "firstName = %@", textInSearchField)
  let lastNamePredicate = NSPredicate(format: "lastName = %@", textInSearchField)
  let idPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "id = %@", textInSearchField)
  let orPredicate = NSCompoundPredicate(type: NSCompoundPredicate.LogicalType.or, subpredicates: [firstAndLast,firstNamePredicate, lastNamePredicate, idPredicate])

  clientsEntity.predicate = orPredicate

  clients = try! context.fetch(clientsEntity) as! [NSManagedObject]
  view.endEditing(true)
  clientTableView.reloadData()

}
```

}

Something to bear in mind is that I still need to be able to use 
**LogicalType.or** since I want to have the option for the user to search by first name, last name but also a combination of both for example **Harold Finch** or **Finch/Harold** etc.

Cheers!

Comment: `NSPredicate(format: "firstName = %@ AND lastName = %@", textInSearchField)` You have two placeholders (`%@`), but only one value (`textInSearchField`). Use at least `NSPredicate(format: "firstName = %@ AND lastName = %@", textInSearchField, textInSearchField)` Also, you could have use a `NSCompoundPredicate` with and `LogicalType.and` combining `lastNamePredicate` and `firstNamePredicate`, and then the create `orPredicate` with that one and `idPredicate`.

Answer (score 0):

```
let firstAndLast = NSPredicate(format: "firstName = %@ AND lastName = %@", textInSearchField)
let firstNamePredicate = NSPredicate(format: "firstName = %@", textInSearchField)
let lastNamePredicate = NSPredicate(format: "lastName = %@", textInSearchField)
let idPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "id = %@", textInSearchField)

let orPredicate = NSCompoundPredicate(type: NSCompoundPredicate.LogicalType.or, subpredicates: [firstAndLast,firstNamePredicate, lastNamePredicate, idPredicate])
```

I hope that for `orPredicate`, it should be `[firstAndLast, idPredicate]` instead, but you didn't make it work. Else you need to rethink about it, that's your `orPredicate` current logic:

```
if ((a == x AND b == x) OR (a == x) OR (b == x) OR (c = x)) {
}
```

The `(a == x AND b == x)` is useless.

There is an issue on that line:

```
let firstAndLast = NSPredicate(format: "firstName = %@ AND lastName = %@", textInSearchField)
```

You have two placeholders (`%@`), but only one argument (`textInSearchField`).

```
let firstAndLast = NSPredicate(format: "firstName = %@ AND lastName = %@", textInSearchField, textInSearchField)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank for the help, I ended up using an alternative method with **contains[c]** my code is below for anyone who needs help with a similar function, you can use contains[c](contains character) to search via character specifically this applies to all strings i.e first name or last name and in my case also an ID which is stored as a String also.

```
func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {

textInSearchField = searchBar.text!

if searchBar.text == ""{

  retrieveClients()
  view.endEditing(true)
  clientTableView.reloadData()

}else{

  isFilteringSearch = true
  let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
  let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
  let words = textInSearchField.components(separatedBy: " ")

  for word in words{

    if (word).count == 0{
      continue
    }

  let firstNamePredicate = NSPredicate(format: "firstName contains[c] %@", word)
  let lastNamePredicate = NSPredicate(format: "lastName contains[c] %@", word)
  let idPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "id contains[c] %@", word)
  let orPredicate = NSCompoundPredicate(type: NSCompoundPredicate.LogicalType.or, subpredicates: [firstNamePredicate, lastNamePredicate, idPredicate])
  clientsEntity.predicate = orPredicate

  }

  clients = try! context.fetch(clientsEntity) as! [NSManagedObject]
  view.endEditing(true)
  clientTableView.reloadData()

}
```

}

I followed the second answer on this post [NSPredicate: Combine CONTAINS with IN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13479542/nspredicate-combine-contains-with-in)

Thank You