# How to perform SQL string contains query in Azure DB with iOS Swift?

Tags: ios, sql, swift, azure

I am trying to execute a string contains query in Azure DB with iOS swift.

However, I got the following error:
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unable to parse the format string "CONTAINS(title,"panda")"'

Following is my code executing the Azure SQL query:

```
static func tableQueryOrderBy(_ tableName: String, queryCondition: String,
                                  orderBy: String, isDescending: Bool,
                                  fetchOffset: Int, fetchLimit: Int,
                                  queryCallBack: @escaping ([AnyObject]?) -> ()) {

        guard let delegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate,
            let client = delegate.client else { return }

        // condition
        guard let table = client.table(withName: tableName) else { return }
        guard let query = MSQuery(table: table) else { return }
        if queryCondition != "" {
            query.predicate = NSPredicate(format: queryCondition)
        }
        isDescending ? query.order(byDescending: orderBy) : query.order(byAscending: orderBy)
        query.fetchOffset = fetchOffset
        query.fetchLimit = fetchLimit
        query.read { result, error in
            if let err = error {
                // print("Query failed: ", err.localizedDescription)
                queryCallBack(nil)

            } else if let items = result?.items {
                // print("Query succeeded!")
                queryCallBack(items as [AnyObject]?)
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally found an example that works by @Sanket Ray, copy-pasted his/her answer here:

```
let firstName = NSPredicate(format: "firstName CONTAINS[c] %@", searchText)
let lastName = NSPredicate(format: "lastName CONTAINS[c] %@", searchText)

let orCompoundPredicate = NSCompoundPredicate(orPredicateWithSubpredicates: 
[firstNamePredicate,lastNamePredicate]
```

Ref: [NSPredicate: Combine CONTAINS with IN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13479542/nspredicate-combine-contains-with-in)